# How to write two same name classes

Tags: python

I'm trying to write two classes with the same name in one file. Something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

class A:
    def __init__(self, id, name,pass):
        self.id=id 
        self.name=name
        self.type=pass
```

and use here:

```
obj1=A(name)
obj2=A(id,name,pass)
```

is it possible?

Comment: Not in my experience. Why do you need to use the same class for each one?

Comment: use kwargs, in the `__init__`

Comment: No, Python does not natively support overloading (which is essentially what you're trying to do here). Read about default arguments

Comment: chances are if you ask a question about what your actually trying to do someone will ikely tell you a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. But:

If you have the same functionality, just want to have different constructors, use default args:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, id=None, pass=None):
        self.id=id 
        self.name=name
        self.type=pass

# These both work
obj1=A(name)
obj2=A(id,name,pass)
```

If you have different functionality: Use different names.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A class declaration is just a declaration, so the second one will overwrite the first, just like doing `x=1; x=2`. What you probably want is alternative constructors for your class. See [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Comment: a single `__init__` with default arguments will probably be enough here

Comment: @DeepSpace: probably, but the post reminded me more of constructor overloading in a java-like class

Answer (score 0):

You could make use the `kwargs` like,

```
$ cat kwargs.py
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id= kwargs.get('id')
        self.name = kwargs.get('name')
        self.type = kwargs.get('type')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}(id={}, name={}, type={})'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            self.id,
            self.name,
            self.type,
        )


obj1 = A(name='foo')
obj2 = A(id='id1', name='foo', type='footype')
print(obj1)
print(obj2)
```

**Output:**

```
$ python kwargs.py
A(id=None, name=foo, type=None)
A(id=id1, name=foo, type=footype)
```